# assigning and echoing values for multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that works if I manually set the values, but does not work if I try to dynamically set the values.

Here is the code that works when I manually set the array values:

```
<?php

//testing creation and output of a multidimensional array
$evt = array("BATT","MGAP","BSTR");
$st = array("Document","Enrollee","Agent","Other");
$ord = array(1,3,2,4);
$prt = array(
  array('evt'=>"BATT",'st'=>"Document",'ord'=>1),
  array('evt'=>"BATT",'st'=>"Enrollee",'ord'=>3),
  array('evt'=>"BATT",'st'=>"Agent",'ord'=>2),
  array('evt'=>"BATT",'st'=>"Other",'ord'=>4),
  array('evt'=>"MGAP",'st'=>"Document",'ord'=>1),
  array('evt'=>"MGAP",'st'=>"Enrollee",'ord'=>3),
  array('evt'=>"MGAP",'st'=>"Agent",'ord'=>2),
  array('evt'=>"MGAP",'st'=>"Other",'ord'=>4),
);

$keys = array_keys($prt);
for ($x=0;$x<count($keys);$x++) {
    echo "UNSORTED: prt key is " . $keys[$x] . "{<br>";
    foreach ($prt[$keys[$x]] as $key=> $value) {
        echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
    }

    echo "}<br>";
}
?>
```

Here is the code that does not work when trying to dynamically set the values:

```
<?php

//testing creation and output of a multidimensional array
$evt = array("BATT","MGAP","BSTR");
$st = array("Document","Enrollee","Agent","Other");
$ord = array(1,3,2,4);    
$prt = array();

for ($x=0;$x<count($evt);$x++) {
    for ($y=0;$y<count($st);$y++) {
        $prt[$x][$y] = array('evt'=>$evt[$x],'st'=>$st[$y],'ord'=>$ord[$y]);
        echo "evt[".$x."] is set to " . $evt[$x] . " and st[".$y."] is set to " . $st[$y] . " and ord[".$y."] is set to " . $ord[$y] . "<br>";
    }
}

$keys = array_keys($prt);
for ($x=0;$x<count($keys);$x++) {
    echo "UNSORTED: prt key is " . $keys[$x] . "{<br>";
    foreach ($prt[$keys[$x]] as $key=> $value) {
        echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
    }

    echo "}<br>";
}
?>
```

Based on the echo statement within the for $y loop, I am getting the right values, but for some reason I am either not storing it correctly, or the foreach loop using $key=>$value isn't working, and I can't figure out which.  I have looked for various solutions to try to set the array dynamically and then access it again dynamically and can't seem to get it to work as expected.  I hope you all can help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$prt[$x][$y] = array('evt'=>$evt[$x],'st'=>$st[$y],'ord'=>$ord[$y]);
```

to this:

```
$prt[] = array('evt'=>$evt[$x],'st'=>$st[$y],'ord'=>$ord[$y]);
```

`$ptr` should be a "flat" array of arrays. In the original code line, what you're actually creating is a multidimensional array, which doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: upvoted yes this was the problem according to OP question, but OP why don't you use foreach() directly instead of use outer for loop and then foreach() this is not a good habit

Comment: Not sure how to accept the answer, but Jose had it right.